# Run a script every time my display turns on?

Tags: command-line, scripts, display

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 using a Nvidia GTX 950. How would I set up a script to run every time my display turns on or wakes up?

Comment: You  don't mean when lid open? right? So by "turns on" what do you mean? or wakeup?

Comment: When I turn my monitor on. If it were a laptop then yeah, every time the lid opens. I don't know if there's a technical difference between pressing the power button or just waking it up by moving my mouse around after it's gone to sleep, would it affect the script?

Comment: Maybe this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433203/how-to-determine-if-lcd-monitor-is-turned-on-from-linux-command-line) will help.

Comment: This might be related to run a script when HDMI screen is plugged or unplugged: https://askubuntu.com/questions/874506/hdmi-monitor-not-detected-by-laptop-after-unplugging-and-plugging-back-in/876684#876684